# Phone Gap - unclear on the concept

Tags: cordova

I just downloaded PhoneGap and created and ran the "HelloWorld" project they suggest on the their web page. What I would like to do next is create an iPhone app based on an existing PHP web page. I'm not clear on how that works. Do I download all the html/css/javascript/images and place them in the WWW folder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you should include all your html/css/javascript/images in the `www` folder. But keep in mind that you can not use PHP or other server side language in a PhoneGap app. You should communicate via JS/Ajax with your server and retrieve dynamic data from there.

Comment: Do I need to pull out the php from the pages and store them as separate files on the server, then use something like $('#content').load('http://www.example.com/test.php'); also what if the display of html is dependent on a php code? There must be some examples somewhere...

Comment: If the result of your `test.php` is HTML then yes, it's exactly what you have to do. Think about a PhoneGap app like a big Ajax application that runs on mobile devices.